# Database design help

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm designing a database that will hold contracts and warranties.  A warranty can link to a contract but doesn't depend on a contract to exist.  How can I define the relationship between the 2?

Comment: I guess contracts can exist without warranties?

Comment: Can a warranty link to multiple contracts? A contract to multiple warranties?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes the contracts can link to multiple warranties but the warranty can exist without a contract.  Not all contracts will have warranties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a contract must link to exactly one warranty, I'd have 2 tables:

```
Contract
  ContractId  (Primary key)
  WarrantyId  (foreign key to Warranty'Warranty_Id
  ...
  ...

Warranty
  Warranty_Id  (Primary key)
  ...
  ...
```

If, on the other hand, a contract can link to none, or more than 1 warranty, then I'd have a junction table instead:

```
Contract
  ContractId  (Primary key)
  ...
  ...

Warranty
  Warranty_Id  (Primary key)
  ...
  ...

ContractWarranty
  ContractId  (Primary key) (Foreign key to Contract table)
  Warranty_Id (Primary key) (Foreign key to Warranty table)
```

Comment: Im not sure how i see the first solution working.  A contract may not have a warranty attached.  Wont that break the relationship between the two tables.  Apologies if i wasnt clear enough

Comment: Thats why I qualified it with: 'Assuming that a contract must link to exactly one warranty'... and the second solution with: 'if on the other hand, a contract can link to none....'

Comment: Cool this is exactley what i need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a place to have a Relationship Table between Contracts and Warranties.

Table: Contract_Warrantee_Rel

```
int RelationshipID
int ContractID
int WarranteeID
```

Comment: Ok so if the warranty has an associated contract then there would be a entry in this table linking the 2.  If not then there wouldnt be an entry.  Seems simple enoughth

Answer (score 0):

```
contract
--------
contract_id Number NOT NULL / Unique
other_stuff

warranty
---------
warranty_id  Number NOT NULL / Unique
contract_id
more_stuff
```

unless the warranty can belong to multiple contracts somehow.. then you need an association class like this:

```
warranty_contract
-----------------
warranty_id
contract_id
effective_dt
other info..
```

Comment: thats not going to work is it?  If i have a warranty without a contract then the relationship wont work